# Argument 'high' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got Series)

Tags: numpy, series

I have been trying to fix this code searching for a solution (see error msg in my header). It seem to have to do with the Indexing of the df series. I see the date when I print but cant address it. I could find a workable way of setting date as index which might be required before conversion to np array ?

```
            import datetime
            import talib
            import numpy as np
            import pandas as pd
            from numpy  import array
            from pandas_datareader import data, wb

            start_date = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
            end_date = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 27)
            stocks = ['AAPL', 'SPY']

            df = data.DataReader(stocks, 'yahoo', start_date, end_date)

            high = pd.DataFrame(df.ix['High'])
            low = pd.DataFrame(df.ix['Low'])
            close = pd.DataFrame(df.ix['Close'])

            for stock in stocks:  
            slowk, slowd = talib.STOCH(high[stock],  
                                   low[stock],  
                                   close[stock],  
                                   fastk_period=5,  
                                   slowk_period=3,  
                                   slowk_matype=0,  
                                   slowd_period=3,  
                                   slowd_matype=0)


            slowk = slowk[-1]  
            slowd = slowd[-1]  
            STO = slowk - slowd  

            print('STO', STO)
```

Comment: I found one mistake whereby I selected rows instead of columns. I rectified that see below but still the same error :-(

Comment: high = pd.DataFrame(df['High'])
                low = pd.DataFrame(df['Low'])
                close = pd.DataFrame(df['Close'])